# selecting values with id other than given

Tags: sql

I want to select all rows from a table called modulecat that do not have an ID simmilar to a list of id's given
Query that selects all id's to exclude: `SELECT * FROM modulecat INNER JOIN modules-modulecat ON modules-modulecat.ModuleCatID = modulecat.ID WHERE ModulesID = ?`

query to be filtered with values from other query: `SELECT * FROM modulecat`

This is what I'm trying to accomplish

full table

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | example1 |
| 1 | example2 |
| 2 | example3 |

with id's 0 and 2 excluded

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example2 |

Comment: I am not surte to undserstand your question but excluding columns is often done thanks to NOT IN : `SELECT id from mytable where id not in (2,, 3, 4)`.  Naturally, you can use a result of a select : `SELECT id from mytable where id not in (Select id from tableRef`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not in` or `not exists`. I would suggest to use second query.

using `Not IN`

```
select * from SELECT * FROM modulecat where id in (SELECT modulecat.id FROM modulecat INNER JOIN modules-modulecat ON modules-modulecat.ModuleCatID = modulecat.ID where WHERE ModulesID = 3 )
```

using `not exists`

```
SELECT * FROM modulecat m WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM modulecat mc INNER JOIN modules-modulecat ON modules-modulecat.ModuleCatID = mc.ID WHERE ModulesID = 3 and m.id=mc.id)
```

Comment: this results in the following query: `SELECT * FROM modulecat WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM modulecat INNER JOIN modules-modulecat ON modules-modulecat.ModuleCatID = modulecat.ID WHERE ModulesID = 3)` but it gives me an error that column ID is not one value

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: @collintersteege I have revised both my answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks the revision fixed my problem thank you for your time